# Изменение TextView при достижении конкретного времени

Tags: android

Условно, есть время 15:32-15:40, мне нужно, чтобы до 15:32 показывало "Текст1", а после 15:32 был "Текст2" и после 15:40 был опять "Текст1", не могу додумать. Спасибо заранее

Comment: Что конкретно-то не получается? Как пытаетесь делать? Нужно включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему.

Comment: конкретно не получается - всё, не могу написать код, который бы работал как я хочу, сам выводил только таймер, но мне он не нужен. Я хочу чтобы у меня высвечивался "Текст2" буквально на пару минут и потом опять сменялся на "Текст1"

Answer (score 0):

1. Зарегистрируйте программно [получатель системного сообщения изменения минут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30209387/3212712).
2. В каждое срабатывание получайте текущее системное время. Например через `new Date()`
3. Проверяйте нужное вам условие и делайте нужные вам действия.